# Access is denied writing to file from ExtendScript

Tags: permissions, filesystems, photoshop, extendscript, photoshop-script

I'm trying to write an ExtendScript script for Photoshop 2024. I am using `app.system()` to execute other programs. I can't figure out how to get a script like that to write a file. I can't get a `>` redirection to write a file nor can I get a Python script to write a file.

For example, `app.system("echo hi > tests.txt; & pause")` will produce the following output:

```
Access is denied.
Press any key to continue . . .
```

Whereas, `app.system("echo hi; & pause")` will produce this:

```
hi;
Press any key to continue . . .
```

I've tried all manner of paths including ones in `Folder.temp` and they all fail similarly.

I've even tried opening the file first in ExtendScript via `f.open("w")` before running my script, and that fails with `The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process.`

This is preventing me from having external programs do work and save their results to a file for me to read in my ExtendScript. It is also preventing me from writing out batch or Python files to execute via `app.system()`.

Answer (score 0):

@Yuri Khristich gave me a huge hint to solving this. He said:

> I just tried `app.system("echo hi > tests.txt; & pause")` and got the same error. Then I tried `app.system("echo hi > d:\\tests.txt; & pause")` and it works just fine. I believe the problem has to do with access to the root folder of the drive C.

Even if running my script as an administrator, I still can't write to the C: drive. Since that is where the files live, I had to get clever with drive letters to work around this. I ended up creating a function that will take any path and map it to an unused drive letter so that I can work around this strange limitation.

```js
function mapNextAvailableDriveLetter(path) {
  var driveLetters = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";

  for (var i = 0; i < driveLetters.length; i++) {
    var result = app.system("subst " + driveLetters[i] + ': "' + path + '"');
    if (result === 0) {
      return driveLetters[i];
    }
  }

  alert("Unable to map a drive letter to " + path);
  exit();
}
```

I pair that function with a function to undo this when my script ends:

```js
function removeSubstDriveLetters() {
  var driveLetters = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
  var cmd = "@echo off";

  for (var i = 0; i < driveLetters.length; i++) {
    cmd = cmd + " & subst " + driveLetters[i] + ": /D >nul 2>nul";
  }

  app.system(cmd);
}
```

I even use this to get access to a temp folder like so: `mapNextAvailableDriveLetter(Folder.temp.fsName)`.

With these two functions I can call external utilities and have them write their output to a file that I can read with ExtendScript. I can also create scripts that I can run via a call to `app.system()`. This greatly extends the ability of my ExtendScript to do work beyond just working with Photoshop.